# How to get Javascript Objects from JavaScriptSerializer?

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0

When I use the `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize` method, I get back valid JSON code.

This is usually perfect, but sometimes I want to get back the result as a Javascript object, not JSON.  The `Serialize` method has an overload that takes a `SerializationFormat` parameter.  That looks perfect... but it is marked as `internal`!

How can I get out a string of Javascript from the Serializer?

Comment: When is it not perfect? The only difference that internal value makes has to do with how it deals with dates.

Comment: ...What's the difference between a JavaScript object and JSON?

Comment: Yes, it was the Dates that gave the biggest headaches.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the JScript DLL Eval object's JScriptEvaluate method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.jscript.eval.jscriptevaluate.aspx):

```
using Microsoft.JScript;
var MyJSObject = Eval.JScriptEvaluate("{a:'Property1',b:'Property2'}", Engine);
```

Comment: This looks interesting, but I don't think it is relevant. I'm trying to get a string containing formatted javascript... not execute the javascript.